# Shared folder user permissions in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, permissions

We use Dropbox quite a lot in our team, but we want to share some stuff with only the senior members of the team - contract info and stuff like that.

The rest of the information, working notes, images, drawings, etc., we want to share with everyone in the team.

Is there way to allow everyone access to a folder via sharing (so it will also show up on their online Dropbox account as well as in the desktop app) but then mark some sub folders as restricted so only certain people with the correct permissions can see them?

Is this available as part of normal Dropbox or Dropbox for Business / Teams?

<sub>I suppose the other alternative is to have a main shared folder and then another folder (outside the main folder) which is shared with just senior members.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

With Dropbox, to keep things simple, **"You can't share a folder that contains a shared folder."**

So no. If you have a folder that is shared, all of its contents are then shared.

But yes, with having different access level data in different folders, this would be possible. As you describe, have a shared folder "Main", and another folder "TOP_SECRET".

It's also worth noting, that if you wouldn't care about actual access rights, but only the convenience of what each party has on their computer, this would be possible. You can change include/exclude the folders that are synced to a specific computer by configuring the client on that computer.

Comment: For what it's worth, this true of virtually all of your cloud shared storage services. Certainly Google Drive works this way.